# How to append the number of line in front of the generated file in shell script without producing a temp file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a program to generate a file like this:

```
./program1 $parameter > tempfile
lineNum=`wc -l tempfile | awk '{print $1}'`
echo $lineNum > myfile
cat tempfile >> myfile
rm -f tempfile
```

I wonder if there is a way to archive this without producing a "tempfile"? I think my way is somehow redundant and hope there will be a better way.

Comment: `wc -l < file` gives just the number.

Comment: In general, there is no way to prepend data to a file - it involves rewriting the entire file. So the options are to either use a temporary file, or load the entire file into memory before rewriting it. If the file is large, the temporary file is a much better option (although if it's truly huge, or if you're running out of file system space, there're potential issues with that, too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not *really* without using a temporary (as `sed -i` will do it for you) but...

```
#!/bin/bash
count=$(./program1 $parameter | tee outputfile | wc -l)
sed -i 1i${count} outputfile
```

This might have the advantage of not requiring to load the whole file in memory. Depending your data file this might or might not be an issue.

Comment: That's right. There must be a temporary file somewhere in the OS. I just wanted a way so that the command will do it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this,

```
sed -i "1i$(wc -l myfile | cut -d' ' -f1)" myfile
```

**(OR)**

```
sed -i "1i$(wc -l < myfile )" myfile
```

**Ex:**

```
./program1 $parameter > myfile
sed -i "1i$(wc -l myfile | cut -d' ' -f1)" myfile
```

Answer (score 1):

other solution : use `nl`. It's a tool that was designed to do just that.

`./program1 $parameter | nl -w1 > myfile`

Here, `-w1` is used to specify line numbers are separated by 1 tab

output :

```
1    something
2    somethingelse
3
4    and now for something completly different
```

If you don't want to use tab as a separator, use the flag `-s"X"`, where X is the separator you want (1 space, 2 spaces, a letter, ...). `./program1 $parameter | nl -w1 -s" " > myfile` will yield :

```
1 something
2 somethingelse
3
4 and now for something completly different
```

Comment: This is not at all what the OP is asking. The desired output seems to be a single line containing the count of the rest of the lines, followed by the original file - not a running line number...

Comment: This is not I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `awk`:

```
./program1 "$parameter" | awk '{lines[++n]=$0}END{print n;for(i=1;i<=n;++i)print lines[i]}' > myfile
```

Example:

```
seq --format='Inline Text %.0f' 1 10 | awk '{lines[++n]=$0}END{print n;for(i=1;i<=n;++i)print lines[i]}'
```

Output:

```
10
Inline Text 1
Inline Text 2
Inline Text 3
Inline Text 4
Inline Text 5
Inline Text 6
Inline Text 7
Inline Text 8
Inline Text 9
Inline Text 10
```

Answer (score 0):

For the fun -- and assuming your files are sufficiently small to not exceed the available memory -- you could use only bash internals for that task:

```
#!/bin/bash

# ...

./program1 $parameter |
    ( mapfile arr; echo ${#arr[@]}; IFS=""; echo -n "${arr[*]}" )
```